# .htaccess do not rewrite if URI includes "admin"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

What kind of rule do I need if I do not want redirect in the administrative panel on site.ru/admin?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(dev\.)?(site\.ru)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2msk\.site\.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below condition above your rule,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
```